# Raspberry Pi in 24/7/365 production

Tags: hardware, video, server

Would you advice to use Raspberry Pi as a server for an advertising display system to manage 150 LCD screens in 24/7/365 mode?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please note that there is already a nice question with answers covering that topic.

Comment: 150 LCD? i dont thing pi is able to handle it on it's tiny 512 MB ram. Just calculate the memory amount needed to be allocated for pixels!